# Google Maps API v3 - Duration from Matrix API Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the duration time from google maps API using["legs"] but I always get a null value.

```swift
do {
                    let jsonData = try JSON(data: data)
                    let routes = jsonData["routes"].arrayValue
                    
           
                    for route in routes {
                        let overview_polyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                        let points = overview_polyline?["points"]?.string
                        let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points ?? "")
                        let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                        polyline.strokeColor = .systemYellow
                        polyline.strokeWidth = 5
                        polyline.map = self.mapView
                    }
                }
                 catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
```

Comment: I see nothing in the code you posted that relates to *getting the duration time*.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score -1):

I just added this code

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSON(data: data)
    let routes = jsonData["routes"].arrayValue
                    
           
    for route in routes {
        let overview_polyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
        
        let legs = route["legs"][0]
        let duration = legs["duration"]["text"]
        print("This is the distance ", duration) 
        
       let points = overview_polyline?["points"]?.string
       let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points ?? "")
       let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
       polyline.strokeColor = .systemYellow
       polyline.strokeWidth = 5
       polyline.map = self.mapView
                    }
                }
                 catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
```